# CFHTTP ReCaptcha V3 Error with Connection

Tags: cfml, recaptcha-v3

So my form used to work however I recently started getting an error it seems to be a connection issue however I cannot figure out how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: Which coldfusion version are you on?

Comment: On CF11 I can go to 2018 if needed